# Customised Java UTF-8

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, utf-8

I have implemented a customized UTF-8 encoding mechanism. The code works fine, but I have a lot of concerns regarding the code.

```
public class Utf8Encoding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

           byte [] arr = new byte[1000];
           int iStr = 95000; // or > 65535, as till 65535 all chars are unicode and above are surrogates.
           String str = new String(Character.toChars(iStr));
           encode(arr,0,str);
           System.out.println(decode(arr,utf8Length(str)));
           System.out.println(decode(arr,utf8Length(str)).equals(str));
    }

    public static byte[] encode(byte[] aByteArray , int offset ,String str) { 

        int len = str.length();
        int j = offset;

        try {
            for (int k = 0; k < len; ++k) {
                int l = str.charAt(k) & 0xFFFF;
                if ((l >= 1) && (l <= 127)) {
                    aByteArray[(j++)] = (byte) l;
                } else if ((l == 0) || ((l >= 128) && (l <= 2047))) {
                    aByteArray[(j++)] = (byte) (192 + (l >> 6));
                    aByteArray[(j++)] = (byte) (128 + (l & 0x3F));
                } else {
                    aByteArray[(j++)] = (byte) (224 + (l >> 12));
                    aByteArray[(j++)] = (byte) (128 + (l >> 6 & 0x3F));
                    aByteArray[(j++)] = (byte) (128 + (l & 0x3F));
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException localArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
            throw new InternalError(
                    "Cannot encode the chracter "+str);
        }

        return aByteArray;

    }
     public static String decode(byte[] aByteArray ,int len) {

         int j = 0;
         int aOffset = 0;
         int i = len;
         char[] charArray = new char[len];
         while ((j < len) && (aByteArray[aOffset] >= 0)) {
                charArray[(j++)] = (char) aByteArray[(aOffset++)];
            }
            while (aOffset < i) {
                int l = aByteArray[(aOffset++)];
                if (l >= 0) {
                    charArray[(j++)] = (char) l;
                } else {
                    int i1;
                    if (l >> 5 == -2) {
                        if (aOffset < i) {
                            i1 = aByteArray[(aOffset++)];
                            charArray[(j++)] = (char) (l << 6 ^ i1 ^ 0xF80);
                        }
                    }
                    int i2;
                    if (l >> 4 == -2) {
                        if (aOffset + 1 < i) {
                            i1 = aByteArray[(aOffset++)];
                            i2 = aByteArray[(aOffset++)];

                            charArray[(j++)] = (char) (l << 12 ^ i1 << 6
                                    ^ i2 ^ 0xFFFE1F80);
                        }

                    }
                    if (l >> 3 == -2) {
                        if (aOffset + 2 < i) {
                            i1 = aByteArray[(aOffset++)];
                            i2 = aByteArray[(aOffset++)];
                            int i3 = aByteArray[(aOffset++)];
                            int i4 = l << 18 ^ i1 << 12 ^ i2 << 6 ^ i3 ^ 0x381F80;

                            charArray[(j++)] = (char) getHighSurrogate(i4);
                            charArray[(j++)] = (char) getLowSurrogate(i4);
                        }


                        }

                    }


                }
            return new String(charArray,0,j);

     }

     public static int utf8Length(String str) {
            int i = str.length();
            int j = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
                int l = str.charAt(k) & 0xFFFF;
                if ((l >= 1) && (l <= 127))
                    ++j;
                else if ((l == 0) || ((l >= 128) && (l <= 2047))) {
                    j += 2;
                } else
                    j += 3;
            }

            return j;
        }

     public static int getLowSurrogate(int number) {
            return (number & 0x3ff) + '\uDC00';
        }

        public static int getHighSurrogate(int number) {
            return (65989 >>> 10)+ ('\uD800' - (0x010000 >>> 10));
        }

}
```

**Few points of concern  :**

1. If I encode the above supplementary character, it is taking 6 bytes. But when I perform
   `str.getBytes("utf8")` it returns only 4 bytes. How many bytes does a surrogate character occupies in UTF-8 ? is it 4 or 6 ?
2. Can we use UTF-8 where we have lots of Non-ASCII / native language characters ? The characters whose code point > 3000 land up occupying 3 bytes ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're reinventing the wheel instead of using the UTF-8 encoder and decoder in the standard API?

Comment: Arrays are bad. Use Collections.

Comment: All code points are "unicode".  Even surrogates.  "utf8" in utf8 only takes 4 bytes.  Surrogates are not part of UTF-8, they are entirely a UTF-16 thing (Java strings use UTF-16).  UTF-8 is _designed_ for non-ASCII/native language characters.  It originally could handle even more codepoints than Java's UTF-16, but then they officially disallowed those extra codepoints.  If you don't know this stuff, maybe you shouldn't be trying to write an encoder.

Answer (score 16):

#### Handling of supplementary characters

No, your code does not handle supplementary characters correctly.  A string encoded in UTF-8 [must not contain high and low surrogate halves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points).  Instead, supplementary characters (in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF) should be encoded as 4-byte UTF-8 sequences.  Your `encode()` function only has three cases, covering 1-, 2-, and 3-byte sequences.

As mentioned in a [previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42658/9357), Java stores its strings internally using UTF-16.  Characters that don't fit into a 16-bit `char` are split into a high surrogate and a low surrogate `char`.  You'll need to detect such surrogates pairs in the string and merge them before encoding.

#### Overlong encoding of <kbd>NUL</kbd>

You encode the <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte as `11000000 10000000`.  According to the specification, that's an [overlong encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings), and it's illegal.

In short, what you have implemented is [Modified UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8).

Comment: But this code encodes and decodes supplementary characters correctly . Just try to encode and decode any supplementary character :)

Comment: As I said, you've implemented Modified UTF-8. You _could_ consider it "correct", but you shouldn't claim that it is proper UTF-8. At the least, you should declare that it is _Modified_ UTF-8 in the JavaDoc, and possibly rename the class as well.

Answer (score 8):

Proceeding with a "regular" code review…

Many of my [previous remarks about your UTF-16 encoder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42664/9357) also apply here.

- The parameters to `encode()` feel backwards to me.
- Your `encode()` lets the caller specify an offset; your `decode()` lets the caller specify a length.  Design consistency would be appreciated.
- Does the `len` parameter to `decode()` specify the number of `byte`s to interpret or the number of `char`s to accept?
- In `encode()`, `int l = str.charAt(k) & 0xFFFF` could just be `int l = str.charAt(k)`.
- The spacing around your commas ,which is inconsistent , is awkward ,though harmless.

The exception handling in `encode()` is perplexing.  An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would not be an [`InternalError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InternalError.html).  You should never throw an `InternalError`, which indicates that the JVM has detected something seriously wrong with itself.  Rather, if an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` does arise, it means that the caller passed in an array that is too small.  The best course of action, in my opinion, is ignore the exception and let it propagate.

As I read it, `decode()` seems to have a serious problem.  Your first while-loop would likely copy the entire `byte` array into the `char` array (with type promotion), probably terminating when `j == len`.  Since `aOffset` is synonymous with `j` (they both get incremented the same number of times in the loop), and `i` is synonymous with `len`, you'll enter the next while-loop with `aOffset == i`, thus skipping the entire second while-loop.

There are already a lot of variables to keep track of.  I don't think you need to add more variables by defining `int j = offset` in `encode()` and `i = len` in `decode()`.

Since you are doing a lot of bit-twiddling, I would find the code easier to understand if you wrote hexadecimal (or [binary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html)) numeric literals instead of base-10 values.  I had to break out my decimal-to-hex converter just to understand your code.

The `getLowSurrogate()` and `getHighSurrogate()` methods have no business being part of the interface of a `Utf8Encoding`.  Such helper methods should be private.